# How to deal with [-Wc++11-extensions] in the text editor

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, gcc-warning

I am experiencing a warning when I try to initialize myCurrentTry to 1 and myMaxTries to 5, the error is:

> in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

The code that is making this happen is:

```
class starUFO{
public:
    void Reset();
    int getMaxTries();
    int getCurrentTry();
    bool isGameWon();
    bool checkGuessValidity(string);
private:
    int myCurrentTry = 1;
    int myMaxTries = 5;
};
```

Ive heard people say "try compiling with -std=c++11" and this does take away the warning in my command line BUT I want to fix the VS Code configuration so it doesn't see this as a warning, I have the latest VS Code but there seems to be a deeper issue.

Comment: Write a constructor and initialize your member variables there.

Comment: @SidS he wants to use the C++11 feature, he just wants to tell VSCode to pass the proper options when it's compiling.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md Check out cppStandard option. I have not used it before so I wont make a full answer.

Comment: If you don't want to compile with C++11 and you don't want to suppress the extension warnings (both of them require changing the compile command line) then don't use C++11 features and you won't get warnings.  If you use a newer version of g++ it will default to C++11 and the warnings will go away - so the best answer is upgrade you g++ compiler.

Comment: @Brittany So to rephrase this question, **How to pass the `-std=c++11` parameter when compiling in VSCode**?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah He has the correct compiler. When he compiles from the shell he can use the `-std` option to suppress the warning. He wants to know how to do the same thing when compiling from the IDE.

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you asked how to "fix the issue in vscode itself". Then you asked how to "fix this warning in the code itself". Do you want to fix the code or the VS Code configuration?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I am new at all of this and just trying to understand whats going on. So you said I need to upgrade my g++ compiler, but I dont know how to do this. I tried to follow (https://arvindrao.wordpress.com/2012/12/31/installing-latest-gccg-via-homebrew/) this but it gives me errors such as, (No available formula with the name "gcc81"), and I used gcc81 because 8.1 is the newest version available ( I think ). Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @Barmar I want to fix the VS Code configuration so it doesn't see this as a warning, I have the latest VS Code but there seems to be a deeper issue.

Comment: Edit the question to make it clear. Did you try the `cppStandard` option mentioned above?

Comment: @Barmar I edited the question, hopefully it is more clear, thank you for helping me sort the wording out. Im honestly not sure what the cppStandard option mentioned above was, or how to implement it. I don't just want to suppress the warning the the compiler but I want my text editor (VS Code) to not see this as a warning.  Sorry again.

Comment: Your gcc version is fine. Show the command line you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Write a constructor and initialize your member variables there :

```
class starUFO
{
    private:
        int myCurrentTry;
        int myMaxTries;

    public:
        starUFO()
        :   myCurrentTry(1),
            myMaxTries(5)
        {
        }

        ...
};
```

Comment: he doesn't want to stop using this feature, he wants to compile it with the option that enables it without printing a warning.

Comment: @Barmar, Let's hear *her* say that.

Comment: He did: **Ive heard people say "try compiling with -std=c++11 and this does take away the warning in my command line but I want to fix the issue in vscode itself.**

Comment: @Barmar, That's still *your* interpretation.  She also says *"Is there a way I can fix this warning in the **code** itself?"*

Comment: He's added a comment explaining what he wants.

Comment: @SidS thank you for your response, and noticing I am female haha, and sorry the question was a bit unclear to begin with. But yes, my goal here is to fix the VS Code configuration itself so that it doesn't see this as an error. I had another issue before (never got resolved) with using constexpr instead of const, and I get an error saying (unknown type name 'constexpr'). Which is leading me to believe there is a deeper issue with my VS Code configuration, and I am just trying to sort through everything to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

To tell VSCode which C++ standard you are using, open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), choose "C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)", scroll down and change the "C++ standard" dropdown.  In this case, choose "c++11" or higher.

This assumes you are using the "IntelliSense" engine, rather than the older "Tag Parser" engine: go to File → Preferences → Settings → C/C++ → "C_Cpp: Intelli Sense Engine", and make sure it is set to "Default".

These options exist in VSCode 1.37.1 and [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) 0.25.1 (a.k.a. "cpptools").  I don't know when they were introduced.